# Does dealloc get called after viewDidUnload

Tags: ios

I have this code below in my `UIViewController`. Does it make sense?

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Or maybe dealloc code will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have the `removeObserver` call in `dealloc`.  `viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called at all (and is in fact deprecated in iOS6).  `dealloc` will eventually be called once all references to your viewcontroller are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Having it inside `dealloc` will be enough, as adding an object as an observer to a notification doesn't increase its reference account. As long as no other references are held, the view controller will be `dealloc`ed when it is removed from its parent view controller.

In fact `viewDidUnload` is definitely the **wrong** place to put it. This method is very rarely called, and since iOS6 it is deprecated and never called at all!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the observer in `dealloc` is a safety net, and you should have a safety net. `viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS6 so it would be used only in older versions of iOS anyway. Generally you should ensure that you remove yourself as an observer in the corresponding method to where you added yourself as an observer (like the view appearing and disappearing).

Comment: So the question becomes, for a viewcontroller, what is a good method to register a notification handler from?  There are many places, and not all have "corresponding methods" to remove them.  E.g. awakeFromNib, or viewDidLoad.  If you want to receive notifications for the lifetime of the viewcontroller then dealloc is the place to deregister, and I wouldn't consider it a 'safety net'

Comment: @TomSwift, true, for a lifetime registration it isn't a safety net it's just correct.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidUnload has been deprecated. iOS calls viewDidUnload under memory stressing conditions. You shouldn't have to use this method under ARC